# How can i close (collapse) all the other collapsable div's except the current one

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery Mobile's Collapsable framework .

How can i close (collapse) all the other collapsable div's except the current clicked one ??

This is my code

```
  $('.my-collaspible').on('collapsibleexpand', function() {
      $(this).off('collapsibleexpand');
    });
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/9/

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.collapsible("collapse")` for collapsing other `.my-collaspible` items:

```
$('.my-collaspible').not(this).collapsible("collapse");
```

### Working Demo

Comment: Thanks , but when i clicked on multiple times , both are getting opend .

Comment: I tried it this way http://jsfiddle.net/10nh59f4/1/ , but i am getting exceptions under browesr console .

Comment: do other attributes are conflicting with attached event??

Comment: you demo work only first time, on second - open both, this line not need: `$(this).off('collapsibleexpand');` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/10nh59f4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how that thing works, maybe messy but i added class magic :D
  This works like you wanted though:

```
$('.my-collaspible').on('collapsibleexpand', function() {
  $('.opened').each(function(){
  $(this).collapsible( "collapse" );
  $(this).removeClass('opened');
  });
  $(this).addClass('opened');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/11/